# How to use jpackage with preview features in Java

Tags: java, executable, jpackage

I am trying to create a Microsoft Windows .exe version of my application using `jpackage`. However, my application uses features that are currently in preview. Here is my build script.

```bash
#compiles with preview features enabled
javac --enable-preview --source 21 -d classes src/Helltaker/Main.java src/module-info.java

#creates the jar file in the run folder
jar --create --file run/HelltakerPathFinder_run_me.jar --main-class Helltaker.Main -C classes .

#deletes the jlink created runtime from previous runs of this script
rm -rf ../_CUSTOM_JAVA_RUNTIME

#creates a minimized version of the Java Runtime and stores it into the _CUSTOM_JAVA_RUNTIME folder
jlink --output ../_CUSTOM_JAVA_RUNTIME --add-modules davidalayachew.HelltakerPathFinder --module-path run

#use jpackage to package it up for installation and running
jpackage \
         --input run \
         --name HelltakerPathFinder \
         --description "A path finding algorithm for the video game Helltaker -- written in Java 20" \
         --main-jar HelltakerPathFinder_run_me.jar \
         --win-console \
         --runtime-image ../_CUSTOM_JAVA_RUNTIME
```

So, I tried it, and it finished without error. A .exe file was created. I moved the executable to a different folder, double clicked it, and then an install started. Once the install finished, I navigated to the newly installed application's location (C:\Program Files\HelltakerPathFinder), opened up a windows terminal there, started the application, and then it failed with the following message.

```
PS C:\Program Files\HelltakerPathFinder> .\HelltakerPathFinder.exe
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Helltaker.Main
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for Helltaker/Main (class file version 65.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

So, I tried running with `--enable-preview` and got this.

```
PS C:\Program Files\HelltakerPathFinder> .\HelltakerPathFinder.exe --enable-preview
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Helltaker.Main
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for Helltaker/Main (class file version 65.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

How do I get this .exe file to run with `--enable-preview`?

Comment: BTW, it looks like your app is modular. So, you should be able to skip the separate `jlink` step, and use `--module davidalayachew.HelltakerPathFinder` instead of `--main-jar <jar>` in the jpackage command (and then you can also drop the `--runtime-image` flag).

Comment: Oh beautiful, ty vm. Is there anywhere I can look to see more documentation about what flags/options are needed if others are activated? Most of the documentation merely explains what each command does, but not how they are related to each other.

Comment: I don't know about documentation specifically for that, but you might find what you need in the user guide: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `--java-options` flag for that:

```
--java-options <java options>
      Options to pass to the Java runtime
      This option can be used multiple times.
```

So, for you that would be:

```
--java-options '--enable-preview'
```